# Find out if a model contains associations described in an array with ids

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have the following models:

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pets
end

class Pet < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person
end
```

Now I have an array with the ids of certain pets, and I want to check if the person owns them all.

```
_pets = [1, 4, 5]

person.owns(_pets)
```

So now I want to find out how to check if the user owns ALL these pets. These means that I want to find out if `_pets` is a subset of all his pets.

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pets

    def owns(_pets)
        # ???
        # Returns true or false
    end
end

class Pet < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person
end
```

Comment: What do you want as a return value?? Boolean true/false? True if person owns all the pets?

Comment: I want the method to return a boolean, if the person owns all those pets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
def owns(_pets)
  pets.where(id: _pets).size == _pets.size
end
```

Comment: This works, except for a small bug. I think you meant to write `id:` instead of `ids:`

Comment: Also given the return value maybe `owns?`

Comment: @engineersmnky Nope, the OP wrote in the comments above: _"I want the method to return a boolean, if the person owns all those pets"_

Comment: Right return a boolean so conventionally this method would be called `owns?`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this option.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :pets

    def owns?(_pets)
        pets_ids = pets.pluck(:id)
        _pets.all? { |id| pets_ids.include? id }
    end
end
```

When `_pets = [1, 4, 5]` you can have the following cases:

```
_pets =    [1, 4, 5]    # to checked
pets_ids = [1, 4]       # from pluck
#=> false


_pets =    [1, 4, 5]    # to checked
pets_ids = [1, 4, 5]    # from pluck
#=> true


_pets =    [1, 4, 5]    # to checked
pets_ids = [1, 4, 5, 6] # from pluck
#=> true
```